# Using uniroot function in r with data from data frame to solve Euler-Lotka equation

Tags: r

I'd like to solve an equation for a variable for each line of a given csv file.
You may know the equation as the Euler-Lotka equation.
That is what I have so far:

```
# seed is needed for reproducible results (otherwise random numbers will      never be the same!)
set.seed(42)

# using the Euler-Lotka equation
# l = survival rate until age x
# m = amount of offspring at age x
# x = age of reproduction
# r = population growth rate
y <- function(r, l1, l2, l3, m1, m2, m3, x1, x2, x3, z){((l1*m1*exp(-r*x1)) + (l2*m2*exp(-r*x2)) + (l3*m3*exp(-r*x3))) - z}

# iterate through each line calculating r and writing it into the respective field
for (i in 1:length(neos_data$jar_no)){

# declare the variables from table (this does not work!!)
l1 <- neos_data$surv_rate_clutch1[i]
l2 <- neos_data$surv_rate_clutch2[i]
l3 <- neos_data$surv_rate_clutch3[i]
m1 <- neos_data$indiv_sum_1_clutch[i]
m2 <- neos_data$indiv_sum_2_clutch[i]
m3 <- neos_data$indiv_sum_3_clutch[i]
x1 <- neos_data$age_clutch_1[i]
x2 <- neos_data$age_clutch_2[i]
x3 <- neos_data$age_clutch_3[i]

# this works, while these numbers are the same as in the data frame
l1 <- 0.9333333
l2 <- 0.9333333
l3 <- 0.9333333
m1 <- 3.4
m2 <- 0
m3 <- 0
x1 <- 9
x2 <- 13
x3 <- 16

  ## uniroot finds a 0 value, so offset function, thats why -z in the upper formula
  r <- uniroot(y, l1=l1, l2=l2, l3=l3, m1=m1, m2=m2, m3=m3, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, z = 1, interval = c(-1, 1))[1] #writing only the result of r into variable

  # write r into table
  neos_data$pop_gr[i] <- r

}
```

As I already commented, uniroot works fine with manual input of values. But when try to load a value from my data frame it gives the error "values of f() have the same sign".

I do understand the meaning of the error itself, but why does it work with the values I insert manually and not with the same values from the data frame (and yes, I have checked the data types).

Would be glad for any help, as what I've seen so far was not helpful in my case :)

EDIT: 
To clearify: I'd like to get a value of r for which the equation becomes 0. This works with the given code very fine as far as I insert the values of the variables as a number. But when I try to pass the value from my data frame, it fails even if the same values are passed.

Comment: The `uniroot` function works in one dimension only. In your case, your `y` function is treated as `f(y) = y(r,...)` where the additional arguments `...` to `y` are the static values you provided. The `uniroot` function works on the assumption that `f` is continuous and therefore a zero can be found in an interval where `f` is positive at one end and negative on the other. Opposite signs for `f` at the interval endpoints is a precondition. So, for example, `uniroot(function(x) x^2, interval=c(-1,1))` will _not_ find the solution `0^2 = 0`. You may be looking for `optimize` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I've red a lot about optimize or optim functions, but still I don't understand the output of these functions. 
Maybe I didn't figure out my desire or I just don't understand the point. I'd like to find out under which value of r the equation becomes 0. In fact it works fine with uniroot (as far as I've tested with known fixed values and result). It just don't work after using values from my data frame    instead of using a fixed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the problem.
There are some lines where each part of the sum becomes 0. At each step where the loop hits the 0s the error occurs and the whole stuff doesn't work. 
This seems natural as the equation is:

```
1 = SUM( l(x) * m(x) * exp(-r*x) )
```

if all l(x) and m(x) are 0 the equation cannot become 1, of course.

I didn't realize this issue as the script didn't work at all. Now, after trying and rewriting and deleting code, somehow it writes the resulting r into the data frame until the line with 0s. That brought me to this conclusion. 
Why does this always happens after hours of trying? :D

However, to solve this issue, I inserted a 0.0001 at the respective fields just to get the loop running. In my case I just want to copy the r values to my data mastersheed. As there are only 3 lines with all 0 (it was because NAs couldn't be handled by uniroot) I will delete those values by hand (NAs won't disturb any further calculation).

Thanks for your help anyway. It dropped me into the right direction :)